# Hopf-Rinow theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

If $(M,g)$ is a riemannian manifold.
 $M$ is complete(geodesically) then any two point can be joined by a geodesic.

Geodesic($\gamma(t))$ is smooth curve such that $\nabla_{\gamma'^{(t)}}\gamma'(t)=0$.  Where $\nabla$ is levi civita connection for metric $g$.

Now question is:  Whether always these curve(geodesic) is real analytic???   Hopf-Rinow theorem proves that there is a smooth curve which is goedesic which joins two points.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The system of equations for a geodesic involves first derivatives of the metric coefficients, so if the metric itself is not real analytic, I wouldn't expect the geodesics to be either.